# Looking for n-tier C# 4 tutorial: stored procs, Entity Framework, pocos, business logic, UI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, poco, n-tier-architecture

I've been tasked with investigating n-tier architecture/design for a new C#.NET winforms project (produce a small app to prototype the proposed approach).

We have lots of stored procs which we want to keep.

We want to learn ORM and Entity Framework has been selected.

We want to keep business objects (pocos) separate from business logic.

We want the UI to be separate, obviously.

Any good on line tutorials which incorporate all these elements? Thanks!

---

UPDATE: maybe a one-size-fits-all tutorial is too ambitious. How about a tutorial about Entity Framework that covers the issues of keeping business objects (pocos) separate from business logic classes?

Comment: Might I strongly suggest not using WinForms for new projects?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Developer Center has a large collection of documents and tutorials that might help.

Data Developer Center:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712908.aspx

Technical articles @ DDC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937699.aspx